# SQLite on Azure website

Tags: azure, sqlite

I've been trying to get SQLite to work on an Azure website. I have deployed everything successfully but I need to point it to a file name for the database. I have looked at creating Blob storage but I'm unsure how to convert this into a file name that SQLite will accept.

I'm sure this has been done as I can see references to other issues related to SQLite on Azure.

I have read http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html.

Comment: Fixed by setting the connection string to: `ConnectionString = "Data Source=" +  HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\App_Data\database.db");` I also had to ftp on to azure website to set up the App_Data folder for the website.  (ftp details are stored in the publish settings that you download btw!!)

Comment: Where did you set up that connectionstring? In Global.asax? You can't do the dynamic stuff directly in web.config. I keep getting "The given path's format is not supported." exceptions, no matter if I fill in the relative or absolute path. It looks like Azure wants '/' slashes instead of '\' ones, but whatever combination I use will cause the invalid path format.

Comment: @LouisSomers .You are getting this error because you need to escape your backslashes. ie you need to use \\ instead of \

Comment: I got this working by moving the database to the wwwroot folder, I think azure only has reference to this folder as it's root folder. Then using as the connection string:
var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\Data\\palm.db");
services.AddDbContext<PalmContext>(options =>
          options.UseSqlite("Data Source=" +path));

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Based on my experience if you want to use SQLite with Azure Websites you can keep the database file within your deployment package so it will stay at the same server where your website is. Azure websites provide 1GB of application storage which is plenty for a database file. Your content with the websites will persist and access to SQLite DB will be fast. This is super easy and you can very easily do with ASP.NET web application or any other.

The problem of choosing Azure Blob storage is that if the database file is stored at Azure Blob storage, there are no API that SQLite can write to that file. So one option you could have is to writing locally first and then syncing to Azure Blob storage back and forth while others on SO may have some other options.  If you want to backup your database file to Azure Blob storage for any reason you sure can do that separately however I think if you choose the have SQLite, the best would be the keep the database file with website to make it simple.

Comment: Hey, Thanks that was what I was after. Simple really! I had the connection string wrong so it was trying to put the database file in the temporary asp.net files

Comment: But, the website can be running from different machines. Your writes will be trapped in only one of them. Am I right?

Comment: I believe @Eduardo Molteni is correct. This will only work if you have a site that is not scaled across multiple machines, or you have a read-only database. In the real world, this will only work for a very narrow set of applications.

Comment: @EduardoMolteni actually, the file system in Azure Websites for any given site is shared across all machines, so the exact same database file will be accessible by all instances of your site.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand how it works. What is exactly the deployment package? Is it the "published files" you do at each release? Is it the repository? If it is the "published files": then every time I make a release, my DB will be overwritten? If it is the repository: how can I access (modify!) this file from the webapp?

Comment: Is there a way I can browse the data in the database?