# What is the correct connection string variable in Azure for Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, azure, .net-core

Trying to use a Sqlite database on Azure with the default dotnet core example app with authentication and authorization. On my local machine, it puts the db at `/Users/me/Projects/myProj/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/myProj.db` - and my `appsettings.json` contains this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=myProj.db"
```

So now when I upload to azure without appsettings.json, I have to configure the connection in the Application Settings -> Connection strings section of azure. Part of the issue I'm having is that when I `git push` from my localhost to azure, the location of the db changes. It gets moved to `d:\home\site\wwwroot`. I know that I have to change the connection string, but my various changes to what I think should make it point there have failed - do I include the "Data Source" part? Or ... do I need the quotes? I saw a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113665/sqlite-on-azure-website) that in a comment to the question that gave an interesting answer, but that didn't work.

What is the right way to enter this into azure's connection strings piece?
[image: Azure connection strings entry]

Comment: may help you in future: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The connectionstring to SQLite should contain `DataSource` like this:

```
Data Source=c:\path\mydb.db;
```

Your SQLite database should be located in the App_data folder of your project. You need to create it manually for .NET core projects.

You could then use [Kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) to inspect your deployed website and figure out where the database file is placed after deployment if you are unsure. Log in to Kudu by navigating to `https://yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net`, i.e. your websites Uri but put **scm** between the name and azurewebsites.net. Log in using the same credentials you use for Azure portal.

You should now see the Kudu portal. Go to **Debug console** and select **CMD** or **PowerShell** (which ever you like). In the top part you will now see  a file explorer and you should be able to find your database file here, if it has been properly deployed.

[image]

Just navigate to `D:\home\site\wwwroot` and see if you have an `App_data` folder. Once you found your database you can put that path into you connection string in the Azure portal and Restart the website.

Another way would be to build the connection string in your code and allowing ASP.NET to mapp the folder for you:

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source=" +
    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\App_Data\mydb.db")‌​;
```

or:

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source=" +
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory") + "mydb.db";
```

Beware though, the space available to your website in `App_data` (or any other disk location) for a website is limited (depending on your tier) and if your database eats up all that your site will crash, your database wont save data and everyone will be sad.

Another option for you would be to use [blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) and put your SQLite database file there.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what a connection string looks like when properly inputted to azure.
I've found the correct location, but seem unable to get it working.