# Proper place to store sqlite.db file in azure Web App

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure

I'm new to azure and I have to save data from a collection,Error Log and API Log in an sqlite db file to use in an azure web api and unable to decide the proper folder to keep the file as various articles say that azure creates multiple instances of a web app.I have read through below articles that multiple instances are created for an azure web app and we can store our db file in d:\home\site\wwwroot\content\data but my project has path only till wwwroot and wanted to know if I have to create a folder called content along with data and will it be common for all the instances as there is no way to test.

1. [Article1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317754/where-to-put-sqlite-database-file-in-azure-app-service)
2. [Article2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113665/sqlite-on-azure-website)

   My Question is if Storing the DB file in d:\home\site\wwwroot\content\data will it be common for all the instances of my web app if no then let me know which is the proper way to store the db file in my web api.

I have tried Blob storage but its of no use as i have to cannot connect to it and need to download a copy of it each time.

Comment: Your first article link above already points exactly to the answer (which I wrote). You just create whatever you want, under `wwwroot`, and then that content is seen by all instances.

Comment: I wanted to confirm that @DavidMakogon as there is no way to test if all instances are using the same path

Comment: Right - I'm saying that, in my answer, I specifically said that each instance shares that space. Which means they all use the exact same path.